# How can i change the placeholder when the Questioncategory is of type SUB for example

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, placeholder

im learning symfony and i want to chance the placeholder when the Questioncategory is of type SUB for example :

```
class AbstractContactType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $questionCategory;

 public function __construct(
        QuestionCategoryRepository $questionCategory,

    ) {
        $this->questionCategory = $questionCategory;
    }
```

I tried to make a simple condition to modify my placeholder in the function:

```
$test = $this->questionCategory->findModule();

if (!$test) {
            $builder->add(
                'content',
                TextareaType::class,
                [
                    'label' => 'Votre demande',
                    'required' => true,
                    'attr' => [
                        'placeholder' => 'Votre demande ...',
                        'rows' => '6',
                    ],
                ]
            );

        } if ($test) {
            $builder->add(
                'content',
                TextareaType::class,
                [
                    'attr' => [
                        'placeholder' => 'Test ...',
                        'rows' => '6',
                    ],
                ]
            );
```

My repository:

```
public function findModule(): QueryBuilder
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->select('t.module')
            ->where('t.module = SUB');
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: there's usually two ways to manipulate what fields (or with which options) are created: setting the option on the form outside the form type (which situationally isn't usable) or using FormEvents, where you can actually access the data in the form.